# Complex eigenvalues and writing $A=PCP^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In writing a real matrix $A$ with non-real eigenvalues in the form $A=PCP^{-1}$, we find two eigenvalues: $\lambda$ and $\overline{\lambda}$. We can find a vector $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{C}^2$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, and then the vector $P$ can be $\begin{bmatrix}Re(\mathbf{v}) & Im(\mathbf{v})\end{bmatrix}$. At that point, our matrix $C$ is $\begin{bmatrix} Re(\overline{\lambda}) & -Im(\overline{\lambda}) \\ Im(\overline{\lambda}) & Re(\overline{\lambda})\end{bmatrix}$. Great.

Alternatively, if we find a vector $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{C}^2$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\overline{\lambda}$, then we use it to write $P$ as above, but we use $C = \begin{bmatrix} Re(\lambda) & -Im(\lambda) \\ Im(\lambda) & Re(\lambda)\end{bmatrix}$.

I'm looking for the most intuitive way to explain why we use one of the two eigenvalues to write down matrix $C$, but the other one - its complex conjugate - to find an eigenvector for writing $P$.

Any insight, especially explanations that will resonate with first-time linear algebra students, would be very welcome.

Comment: What prevents you from using an eigenvector of $\lambda$ to form $P$ in the first place? The only difference in the result is that the signs of the off-diagonal elements of $C$ are swapped.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't answer the question; it only changes how I would word it. Why swap the signs on those off-diagonal elements? Is there an intuitive explanation for why this works the way it does - that's what I'm asking.

Comment: At root, I suspect it’s because $i^2=-1$. I’d look for clues in the proof that taking real and imaginary parts of complex eigenvalues of a real matrix like this is kosher.